# I have a Windows 7 desktop and an OSX laptop. My keyboard, mouse, monitor are plugged into desktop. Can I switch them for use with the laptop?

Tags: windows-7, display, keyboard, mouse, osx-snow-leopard

As the question states, I would like a way to quickly switch (from software) between my laptop and desktop.  The laptop is a Snow Leopard macbook, and the desktop is a Windows 7 machine.   How can I do this?

Comment: You're looking for a KVM switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a software solution - [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) - it works very well.

Comment: I was looking at this.  Very cool.  It doesn't seem to handle monitors at all though, does it

Comment: You want to have both systems on the same monitor?  Then wouldn't something like RDP/VNC do what you need?  Otherwise, the only reasonable option is a KVM switch like Raystafarian mentioned